# Reliance Netconnect+ in Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, modem

I have A Huwaei Reliance Netconnect+ modem.. To use it with Ubuntu I need to first boot into Windows use it for a while and then restart and go to Ubuntu..Else its not detected as a modem or a usb drive in Linux... I have tried almost every method using wvdial configuration.. 
Any solution to this? Do my UEFI settings make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your modem is EC1260.

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 13.04, here's how I solved it -

1. Check the 'lsusb' output -

   `$ lsusb`
2. If your modem is not isted as something like this -

   `Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card`

   It means that usb-modeswitch is not working.
3. To fix it I cooked up a simple script -

copy the config tar to /tmp for extraction -

`cp /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz /tmp`

unzip it

`gunzip configPack.tar.gz`

extract the tar

`tar xvf configPack.tar`

copy to required directory

`sudo cp 12d1:1446 /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`

finally execute usb_modeswitch.

`sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -D -s 5 -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1446 -u -1   -v 12d1 -p 1446`

If it fails try again (usually works the second time). And even after this it doesn't works then it might be a bug please [report it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-modeswitch)

Answer (score 1):

Make a connection using below :

Go to Network Connection -> Mobile Broadband -> Add

Now there are 5 simple steps; select the natural options:

Select appropriate mobile device : Huwaei
Choose country provider/region : (for Me, India)
Choose your provider : Reliance
Choose your Billing Plan : NetConnect (Accordingly)
Confirm Mobile broadband settings (confirm)

User Name / Password : your 10 digits mobile no. and you're good to go. :) All the Best.